# Re-positioning controls on a form

Tags: c#

The following piece of code is used to re-position controls on a form considering different options.

Once you have multiple controls this becomes quite messy. I would appreciate your improvement suggestions.

```
private void dlgOptionsForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_hideAccountingOption)
        {
            grpAccountingOption.Visible = false;
            Height -= grpAccountingOption.Height;

            grpPeriod.Top -= (grpAccountingOption.Height + 8);
            grpPrintOptions.Top -= (grpAccountingOption.Height + 8);
            grpInvoiceInformation.Top -= (grpAccountingOption.Height + 8);
            grpHND.Top -= (grpAccountingOption.Height + 8);
            chkPrint.Checked = false;
            grpArchiveDocument.Top -= (grpAccountingOption.Height + 8);
            grpBalanceControlList.Top -= (grpAccountingOption.Height + 8);
        }

        if (_hidePeriod)
        {
            grpPeriod.Visible = false;
            Height -= grpPeriod.Height;

            grpPrintOptions.Top -= (grpPeriod.Height + 8);
            grpInvoiceInformation.Top -= (grpPeriod.Height + 8);
            grpHND.Top -= (grpPeriod.Height + 8);
            chkPrint.Checked = false;
            grpArchiveDocument.Top -= (grpPeriod.Height + 8);
            grpBalanceControlList.Top -= (grpPeriod.Height + 8);
        }

        if (_hidePrintOptions)
        {
            grpPrintOptions.Visible = false;
            this.Height -= grpPrintOptions.Height;
            grpInvoiceInformation.Top -= (grpPrintOptions.Height + 8);
            grpHND.Top -= (grpPrintOptions.Height + 8);
            chkPrint.Checked = false;
            grpArchiveDocument.Top -= (grpPrintOptions.Height + 8);
            grpBalanceControlList.Top -= (grpPrintOptions.Height + 8);
        }

        ....
    }
```

Comment: If you have to do this, then I think you are doing something wrong. When controls are not in one position but dance all over the screen, it confuses the user. Be nice to the user. Save "clever" code for something that happens under the hood, not on screen. http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/mct/2740/IN/steinja/lessons/04/krug_chapter_06/krug_6_street_signs_breadcrumbs_02.html?m=1

Here is an example of a nice tabbed dialog in action: http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/fillslinesandeffects/images/solidfills_02.gif

You can hide individual tabs!

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

If all of your grp* inherits of the same object (say Control), what you can do is:

```
private List<Control> _groups = new List<Control>();

.ctor()
{
   // Populate _groups
   _groups.Add(grpPeriod);
   _groups.Add(grpPrintOptions);
   _groups.Add(grpInvoiceInformation);
   _groups.Add(grpHND);
   _groups.Add(grpArchiveDocument);
   _groups.Add(grpBalanceControlList);
}
```

Now you method becomes:

```
private void dlgOptionsForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (_hideAccountingOption)
    {      
        Adjust(grpAccountingOption);
    }
    if (_hidePeriod)
    {
        Adjust(grpPeriod);
    }

    if (_hidePrintOptions)
    {
        Adjust(grpPrintOptions);
    }

    ....
}

private void Adjust(Control control)
{
    control.Visible = false;
    this.Height -= control.Height;
    chkPrint.Checked = false;

    foreach (var item in _groups)
    {
        if(control != item)
            item.Top -= (control.Height + 8);
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT

Solution 2:

```
Dictionary<Func<bool>, Control> _groups= new Dictionary<Func<bool>, Control>();

.ctor()
{
   // Populate _groups
   _groups.Add(() => _hidePeriod, grpPeriod);
   _groups.Add(() => _hideInvoiceInformation, grpInvoiceInformation);
   _groups.Add(() => /* your bool variable */, /* the associated control */);
   // ...
}

private void dlgOptionsForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in _groups)
    {
        if (item.Key()) // Evaluate the boolean variable
            Adjust(item.Value);
    }
}

private void Adjust(Control control)
{
    control.Visible = false;
    this.Height -= control.Height;
    chkPrint.Checked = false;

    foreach (var item in _groups)
    {
        if(control != item)
            item.Top -= (control.Height + 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `.ctor(){ ... }` c++ ? Will this compile as c#?

Comment: It is, I've written '.ctor' in order to explicitely say that it needs to be in it (I've not the name of his class ;-))

Comment: Ah, I see, makes sense. Perhaps something like `public MyClass(){ ... }` would be explicit; and perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
  private const int _standardInterval = 8;

//  private void dlgOptionsForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
//  Type signatures like this are useless as they don't tell you what the method is about
//  (an important aspect of good naming) and contain parameters which you don't use
//  This can be solved with inline lambdas
//  The wire-up which used to be something like
//    form.Load += dlgOptionsForm_Load;
//  Can now be changed to
//    form.Load += (o,e) => RepositionControls();
//  Yes, I am suggesting that the microsoft guidance here is wrong. Most developers that I respect
//  do it this way.
    private RepositionControls()
    {
        if (_hideAccountingOption)
            HideOption(grpAccountingOption, dependencies: new Control[] { grpPeriod, grpPrintOptions, grpInvoiceInformation, grpHND, grpArchiveDocument, grpBlanceControlList });
        if (_hidePeriod)
            HideOption(grpPeriod, dependencies: new Control[] { grpPrintOptions, grpInvoiceInformation, grpHND, grpArchiveDocument, grpBlanceControlList });
        if (_hidePrintOptions)
            HideOption(grpPrintOptions, dependencies: new Control[] { grpInvoiceInformation, grpHND, grpArchiveDocument, grpBlanceControlList });
        //You're always doing this anyways
        chkPrint.Checked = false;
    }

    void HideOption(Control option, Control[] dependencies) {
        option.Visible = false;
        this.Height -= option.Height
        AdjustTopTo(option.Height, dependencies);
    }

    // I am assuming the .Top property is on the Control class and that that is the most common subtype...it's been a while
    // since I've done winforms but I think this is right, if not, change it to what it should be.
    private void AdjustTopTo(int height, params Control[] controls) {
        for(var c in controls)
            c.Top -= (height + _standardInterval)
    }
```

Note that I'm assuming c# 4.0 for the named properties, if you're using a lower version of C# remove the "dependencies:" from the HideOptions invocation. I am also assuming >C#3.5 for the inline lambda, if you are using a lower version than that even (sucks for you) then you'll have to keep the method signature the same.

I will also point out that the only real logic in these if statements is the knowledge of which options depend on which others. There is probably a better way of doing this if you show us more of your code.